# Import an array from the redux store to a table. React,js

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux, store

I am trying to import data from the redux store and render in a table.

I tried a lot of times but always get this error: objects are not valid as a react child (found: object with keys {}). if you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I think i should use a .map method but i don't know how when i get the data with an useSelector

**This is my redux store**

[image: Redux store]

**The table which I want to render the data**

```
<table className="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style={{ width: 100 }}>ID</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Nombre</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Precio</th>
                <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Stock</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I used an useSelector to get the data from the store

```
const { body } = useSelector( state => state.coffe );
```

But now how can i render the data?

Or i'm doing something wrong?

Could someone help me figure it out? Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check body is returning the data. If yes use this code

```
const Table = () => {
    const { body } = useSelector( state => state.coffe );
    return (
        <table className="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style={{ width: 100 }}>ID</th>
                    <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Nombre</th>
                    <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Precio</th>
                    <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {body && body.map( b => 
                    <tr key={b.id}>
                        <td>{b.nombre}</td>
                        <td>{b.precio}</td>
                        <td>{b.stock}</td>
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

export default Table;

To render the data you need to use the map function.

Comment: Thank you very much!! i really appreciate it